# Why do we need to pee more than usual out in cold weather?

Tags: cold-weather

I noticed I have to pee more than usual out in cold weather. Does anyone have a scientific explanation for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The phenomenon name is *cold diuresis*.

From [thefreedictionary.com](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/cold+diuresis):

> [cold diuresis] occurs in hypothermia as a result of peripheral vasoconstriction, hyperglycemia and decreased renal tubular absorption.

You can easily find [articles](http://www.outsideonline.com/fitness/fitness-coach/Why-Do-Cold-Temperatures-Make-Me-Pee.html) and [papers](http://ajprenal.physiology.org/content/244/2/F210) on the subject on the Internet.

Comment: Which roughly translates to vascular system capacity reduction coupled with reduced fluid reabsorption increases relative blood volume and so increases blood pressure and blood sugar by volume causing the body to react to reduce blood volume by extraction through the kidneys to the bladder.

Comment: @stevemarvell I thought it was pretty obvious that's what ppl meant - but thanks for the clarification ;) </cheeky>